# Get new location from Quaternion and Vector3 in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Vector3 and a Quaternion, what is the best way to get the coordinates of a location a certain distance in front (or behind).

What I am trying to do is this:

```
Gizmos.color = Color.red;
var direction = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 1000;
Gizmos.DrawRay(transform.position, direction);
```

Just without access to the transform, but with the (Quaternion) rotation and and coordinates (Vector3)

Comment: What do you mean by *"without access to the transform"*?

Comment: That I only have the coordinates and rotation in a form of a Quaternion.

Comment: There should be plenty of tutorials and resources about vectors and quaternions available on the Internet. Have you done any research? What are the things you've tried? Why are they not working? Perhaps also take another look at [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Yes, I have searched around a bit. And this is not a bug, or anything. I dont know how to do something som the best example I have is some code that delivers me the similar result, except I dont have access to the helper function TransformDirection, but I have the position and rotation. I was hoping unity had a function that could help me, if not I would have to break out some good old math. Hoping to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you multiply a world rotation with `Vector3.forward` you will get the same as using the respective transform.forward

```
public Vector3 GetPosition(Quaternion rotation, Vector3 position, float distance)
{
    Vector3 direction = rotation * Vector3.forward;
    return position + (direction  * distance);
}
```

You could use `Ray` but that would be overkill

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried this, but I had a bug, so I discarded this as a solution. I tried it again when I saw your suggestion and this time it worked. Dont know what I did wrong the last time. I will mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test but this should work

```
Vec3 location = transform.forward*distance + transform.position;
```

distance is unit length from gameObject here.

Edit:

So, there is no transform. And we should generate forward from quaternion. I looked how Unity3D calculate transform.forward and found it here : 
[Unity3D Transform](https://github.com/MattRix/UnityDecompiled/blob/master/UnityEngine/UnityEngine/Transform.cs)

```
public Vector3 forward
{
    get
    {
        return this.rotation * Vector3.forward;
    }
    set
    {
        this.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(value);
    }
}
```

You have a Quaternion rotation and you a Vec3 position as you said in question. So, you can convert this function like this:

```
Vec3 location = rotation*Vector3.forward*distance + position;
```

Comment: Yes that would work. If I had a transform. Now, the transform.forward is the magic I dont have access to here. So either I have to break out the math, or there is a unity function I can use. All the information is in the position and rotation.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood this situation. I edited the answer, I hope this works

Answer (score 1):

The [`Ray`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Ray.html) struct and its [`GetPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Ray.GetPoint.html) function is used to calculate an unknown distance by just providing the starting point, direction and the distance you want it to find.

Let's say this is the location and direction

```
Vector3 startingPostion = new Vector3(4, 6, 2);
Quaternion theDirection = Quaternion.identity;
```

Find distance in 100 meters.

```
Ray ray = new Ray();
//Set the starting point
ray.origin = startingPostion;
//Set the direction
ray.direction = Vector3.forward + theDirection.eulerAngles;

//Get the distance 
ray.GetPoint(100);
```

Or

```
Ray ray = new Ray(startingPostion, worldRotation * Vector3.forward);
//Get the distance 
ray.GetPoint(100);
```

Comment: Programmer i see you added another example, the second one will not work as it does not take the rotation into consideration, perhaps multiply the forward direction by the rotation, Once you do that I would even say your answer is more complete than mine.

Comment: @RiaanWalters I forgot the rotation. Thanks for the edit.